# Miktrotik: disconnect TCP connection

Tags: networking, tcp, tls, mikrotik-routeros

I am working on a mobile device project. I have the mobile device connected on a local USB Wifi hotspot on an Ubuntu PC and I can WireShark the TLS connections which the mobile device creates towards the backend (I can see the IP addresses plus port numbers for the TLS connection in WireShark).

I would like to test what happens when one specific TLS connection disconnects for whatever reason. Therefore I used WinBox on my office MikroTik router. And I can find the specific TLS connection in IP|Firewall|tab Connections.

Can I somehow terminate a TLS connections using the MikroTik router such that it will send a FIN?